# Shading around circles and ellipses

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading

I have a circle inside an ellipse and am wanting to shade inside the circle (which could be done by drawing a filled circle) and outside the ellipse.

I am using tikz axis package to draw the shapes and was trying to use the shade between package to do the shading. I am not attached to keeping them that way, but I do not want to mess with the package settings. There might be a way to use the even-odd rule, but I do not have a lot of practice with it.

Here is the graph that I have thus far (obviously it is not correct):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     %for graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     %to run newest version
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6,
  axis lines=middle,
  ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
   xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
  xlabel = \(x\),
  ylabel = \(y\),
    legend style={legend pos=north east,font=\tiny}
]

\addplot[name path = A,
   domain=-pi:pi,
   samples=200]({5*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
\addlegendentry{\(\frac{x^{2}}{25} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} = 1\)}

\addplot[name path = B,
   domain=-pi:pi,
   samples=200]({3*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
\addlegendentry{\(x^{2} + y^{2} = 9\)}

\path[name path = C] (-6,-6) -- (6,-6);

\path[name path = D] (-6,6) -- (6,6);
    
    \addplot[only marks,black] coordinates {(0,3) (0,-3)};
    
    \addplot[blue!70,opacity=0.4] fill between  [of=A and C];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am still hoping for an answer on this. The main issue is that it is on a colored background already. Thus, I really need a solve that shades the overlapping inside region (which has a great solve below) and shades outside the ellipse. The shading outside the ellipse seems to be the difficult part, and I can not seem to find a solve for it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking to achieve

I have only added the line

`\addplot[blue!70,opacity=0.4,even odd rule] fill between  [of=B and C];`

Also deleted line

`\path[name path = D] (-6,-6) -- (6,-6);`

since it is a duplicate of `name path= C`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     %for graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     %to run newest version
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6,
            axis lines=middle,
            ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
            xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
            ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
            xlabel = \(x\),
            ylabel = \(y\),
            legend style={legend pos=north east,font=\tiny}
            ]
            
            \addplot[name path = A,
            domain=-pi:pi,
            samples=200]({5*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
            \addlegendentry{\(\frac{x^{2}}{25} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} = 1\)}
            
            \addplot[name path = B,
            domain=-pi:pi,
            samples=200]({3*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
            \addlegendentry{\(x^{2} + y^{2} = 9\)}
            
            \path[name path = C] (-6,-6) -- (6,-6);
            
            \addplot[only marks,black] coordinates {(0,3) (0,-3)};
            
            \addplot[blue!70,opacity=0.4,even odd rule] fill between  [of=B and C];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT

You could also reduce `path C` to a point source by defining it as

```
\path[name path = C] (0,0) -- (0,0);
```

Then the output would reduce to only the ellipse and circle

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     %for graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     %to run newest version
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6,
            axis lines=middle,
            ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
            xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
            ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
            xlabel = \(x\),
            ylabel = \(y\),
            legend style={legend pos=north east,font=\tiny}
            ]
            
            \addplot[name path = A,
            domain=-pi:pi,
            samples=200]({5*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
            \addlegendentry{\(\frac{x^{2}}{25} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} = 1\)}
            
            \addplot[name path = B,
            domain=-pi:pi,
            samples=200]({3*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
            \addlegendentry{\(x^{2} + y^{2} = 9\)}
            
            \path[name path = C] (0,0) -- (0,0);
            
            \addplot[only marks,black] coordinates {(0,3) (0,-3)};
            
            \addplot[blue!70,opacity=0.4,even odd rule] fill between  [of=B and C];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I fixed the error on path D. That was supposed to be at 6, not -6. This certainly achieves the coloring inside the circle without me changing much, but would this work for shading outside the ellipse also?

Comment: While I haven't gotten to mess with this as much as I would have liked, I have not yet had success in using this method to shade outside the larger ellipse. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Like this (change colors as You like and add equations where You like):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[red!50] (-5.3,-5.3) rectangle (5.3,5.3);
        %\filldraw[green!3](-5.2,-5.2) rectangle (5.4,5.4);
        \filldraw[white] (0,0) ellipse (5 and 3);
        \filldraw[red!50] (0,0) circle(3);
        \draw[cyan,-latex] (-5.2,0)--(5.4,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,5}
            \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below] () {$\x$};
        \draw[cyan,-latex] (0,-5.2)--(0,5.4) node[above] () {$y$};
        \foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5}
        \draw (.1,\y)--(-.1,\y)  node[left] () {$\y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not be on a white background. While this does achieve the shading that I am looking for, I am looking for something that will blend with the background. I suppose that I could use a similar approach and try to match colors.