# Shading outside an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading

This is related to another questions I posted ([Shading around circles and ellipses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665269/278470)). As I have only gotten a partial answer, I wanted to post a more narrow question to see if I can get the rest figured out.

I have a system of nonlinear equations that yield a circle inside an ellipse. The region of feasibility is inside the circle and outside the ellipse. I found a satisfactory answer for shading inside the circle in my previous question, which will be shown in the answer below.

I am wanting to extend the result to shading outside the ellipse as well. I want to be clear, using filldraw for the surrounding rectangle (the entire axis) does not work (as I have been able to implement it) as it leaves a "haziness" to the axis numbers.

I would prefer to work inside the axis environment as well and keep my functions defined as they are. This would give an approach that would be more flexible for future examples.

In essence the workaround for systems of linear equations is to make a path at the top or bottom of the axis and use them in fillbetween. I am hoping for a similar result here.

The below image shows my current picture. You can see the "haziness" mentioned. I want that region to not be shaded instead.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     %for graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     %to run newest version
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagecolor{green}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6,
  axis lines=middle,
  ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
   xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
  xlabel = \(x\),
  ylabel = \(y\),
    legend style={legend pos=north east,font=\tiny}
]

\addplot[name path = A,
   domain=-pi:pi,
   samples=200]({5*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
\addlegendentry{\(\frac{x^{2}}{25} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} = 1\)}

\addplot[name path = B,
   domain=-pi:pi,
   samples=200]({3*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
\addlegendentry{\(x^{2} + y^{2} = 9\)}

\path[name path = C] (0,0) -- (0,0);

    \addplot[only marks,black] coordinates {(0,3) (0,-3)};

      \filldraw[blue!70,opacity=0.4] (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
        
        \filldraw[green,opacity=0.4] (0,0) ellipse (5 and 3);

    \addplot[blue!70,opacity=0.4] fill between [of=B and C];        
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: Could you add pictures showing both the current output as well as the one you intend? Is path C supposed to be `(-6,0) -- (6,0)`?

Comment: I removed that line. It was an artifact from a previous attempt I had made. I tried to add the image and it shows up when I go to edit...hopefully it will appear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want your fill to cover your axis, then use the option `axis on top`. No need to use layers(explicit), `opacity` or `fillbetween`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-6, xmax=6,
ymin=-6, ymax=6,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\),
legend style={legend pos=north east, font=\tiny},
axis on top,
]
\fill[green!40, even odd rule]
   (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east)
   plot[domain=-pi:pi, samples=50, smooth] ({5*sin(deg(\x))}, {3*cos(deg(\x))}) -- cycle
   plot[domain=-pi:pi, samples=50, smooth] ({3*sin(deg(\x))}, {3*cos(deg(\x))}) -- cycle;
\addplot[domain=-pi:pi, samples=50, smooth]({5*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
\addlegendentry{\(\frac{x^{2}}{25} + \frac{y^{2}}{9}=1\)};
\addplot[domain=-pi:pi, samples=50, smooth]({3*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
\addlegendentry{\(x^{2} + y^{2}=9\)}
\addplot[only marks] coordinates {(0,3) (0,-3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with circle, ellipse and filled area]

Comment: I selected this solution. It required the least amount of modification and was the most flexible. This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use of layers and clipping would suit you:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagecolor{Dandelion!20}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6,
        axis lines=middle,
        ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
        xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
        ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
        xlabel = \(x\),
        ylabel = \(y\),
        legend style={legend pos=north east,font=\tiny},
        layers/my layer set/.define layer set={
          pre main,
          main}{},
        set layers=my layer set,
      ]
    \addplot[
        name path=A,
        domain=-pi:pi,
        samples=200
      ]({5*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
    \addlegendentry{\(\frac{x^{2}}{25} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} = 1\)}
    \addplot[
        name path=B,
        domain=-pi:pi,
        samples=200
      ]({3*sin(deg(x))}, {3*cos(deg(x))});
    \addlegendentry{\(x^{2} + y^{2} = 9\)}
    \path[name path = C] (0,0) -- (0,0);
    \addplot[only marks,black] coordinates {(0,3) (0,-3)};
    \addplot[blue!30] fill between [of=B and C];
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{pre main}
      \clip (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6) (0,0) ellipse (5 and 3);
      \fill[blue!30] (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is a good solution. I only didn't pick it as the other answer did not require quite as much modification.